# GROUP BY ordering

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query in mysql:

```
select territory_id, platform_type_id, p.store_url 
    from main_itemmaster m 
    inner join main_iteminstance i on m.id=i.master_id 
    inner join main_territorypricing p on p.item_id=i.id
    inner join main_territorypricingavail a on a.tp_id=p.id 
    where imdb_url = 'http://imdb.com/title/tt1576422/' 
group by platform_type_id
```

Which gives me the following:

```
territory_id    platform_type_id    store_url
US  Amazon  http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00EQIHJAG
PT  ITUNES  https://itunes.apple.com/pt/movie/id582142080
```

However, I want to do a `GROUP BY` to return the territory_id="US" first if that exists. How would I do that?

This is one way I tried which looks quite dirty but does work in the version of mysql I'm using:

```
select * from 
(select territory_id, platform_type_id, p.store_url from main_itemmaster m 
    inner join main_iteminstance i on m.id=i.master_id 
    inner join main_territorypricing p on p.item_id=i.id 
    inner join main_territorypricingavail a on a.tp_id=p.id 
 where imdb_url = 'http://imdb.com/title/tt1576422/'
 order by territory_id='us' desc
) x group by platform_type_id
```

Which gives:

```
territory_id    platform_type_id    store_url
US  Amazon  http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00EQIHJAG
US  ITUNES  https://itunes.apple.com/us/movie/id582142080
```

Which is the correct result set I'm looking to get.

Here is a link to a SQL fiddle. I condensed all the data into one table to focus on the GROUP BY statement: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81c3b6/2/0

Comment: Your query is malformed because the `select` list is incompatible with the `group by` columns.

Comment: If you need rows returned in a specific order, then add an ORDER BY clause. Other databases would object to this query, raising an error about "non-aggregate expression in SELECT list not in GROUP BY". A MySQL specific extension (enabled by default) allows the query to execute. Are you sure you need or want a GROUP BY operation?

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's MySQL. It accepts this without errors unless configured otherwise :(

Comment: you're using grouping without ANY aggregate functions, which generally negates the point of having grouped in the first place.

Comment: @MarcB what would be a better way to do the above then?

Comment: no idea. that's up to you. but since you're NOT using aggregate functions, mysql is free to choose which record it'll use as the data source for the non-grouped fields. That's generally the FIRST encountered record, but that's not set in stone. it could be ANY random record.

Comment: Marc B is correct. It is indeterminate which value will be returned, there is no guarantee which value will be returned. @David542: The column references in the query aren't qualified with the tablename or a table alias, so the poor reader hasn't a clue which table each column is being returned from. Even if we had the database available, we would still have to go look. Please, for the love of all that is good and beautiful in this world, *qualify* the column references.

Comment: @spencer7593 Marc B thanks for the feedback, I've added a sql fiddle in the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from the comments and the addition of the SqlFiddle it actually seems like you want to create a partitioned row number with a precedence on US per platform and then select the first record.  One way of doing partitioned Row Numbers in mysql is to use variables here is an example:

```
SELECT
  territory_id
  ,platform_type_id
  ,store_url
FROM
( SELECT
    *
    ,@PlatFormRowNum:= IF(@prevplatform = platform_type_id, @PlatFormRowNum + 1, 1) as PlatformRowNum
    ,@prevplatform:= platform_type_id
  FROM
    main_itemmaster m
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prevplatform:='',@PlatFormRowNum=0) var
  ORDER BY
    platform_type_id
    ,CASE WHEN territory_id = 'US' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    ,territory_id
) t
WHERE
  t.PlatformRowNum = 1
ORDER BY
  t.platform_type_id
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81c3b6/12

Basically this partitions the row number by platform, orders US before any other territory and then selects the first row foreach platform.  The one question/trick is how do you choose which to return when US is not available for the platform simply the ascending alphabetical order of the territory_id?

Comment: no that doesn't work, because it's doing the `GROUP BY` statement before the `ORDER BY`, so I still get the same results.

Comment: @David542 I am not following your reasoning why it would give you the same results? The group by happens and then the order by is determined so it should happen after the fact which is why several of us answered teh same.  Are we missing something of how you want the results?

Comment: this gives me 52 results but I'm just looking for 2 results. One for US-Amazon and one for US-iTunes.

Comment: @David542 so you only want US results if a US result exists or you want ALL other non-US results?

Comment: please see updated question, with new example and correct result set.

Comment: @David542 I had seen the updated question and it says you would want US first it doesn't say you would want US only.  So I assume based on your comment of wanting only 2 results that you want only US results if a US result exists.  But the question is that still wanting a result per link or per table.  I would recommend including some example data with your desired result as clearly a number of us are not understanding what you want.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I added a sqlfiddle in the question now.

Comment: updated an answer that might be what you are looking for