# Pre-ordering a GROUP BY statement

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a follow-up to a previous question: [GROUP BY ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498688/group-by-ordering).

I have the following sql table and data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81c3b6/2/0.

The basic un-ordered SQL statement is:

```
SELECT territory_id, platform_type_id, store_url
FROM main_itemmaster
GROUP BY platform_type_id
```

I want to get a single entry for each `platform_type_id` that is in the table, with a preference for `territory_id='US'`. That is, if an entry exists where `territory_id='US'`, I would like to grab that one in the `GROUP BY` statement.

What would be the correct SQL statement to return the GROUPed by statement with a preference for the US item first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GROUP BY ordering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498688/group-by-ordering)

Comment: your last question morphed into this so you have now asked the same question twice.  Gordon's technique below is the same technique I presented you with in my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, the safest way to do this probably involves variables:

```
select im.*
from (select im.*,
             (@rn := if(@p = platform_type_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@p := platform_type_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from main_itemmaster im cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @p := '') params
      order by platform_type_id, (territory_id = 'US') desc
     ) im
where rn = 1;
```

The does not involve using the MySQL (mis)feature that permits columns in the `SELECT` of an aggregation query that are not aggregated and not in the `GROUP BY`.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81c3b6/28) is a SQL Fiddle showing it working.

EDIT:

On the subject of the order of evaluation of variables.  From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html):

> As a general rule, other than in `SET` statements, you should never
>   assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same
>   statement. For example, to increment a variable, this is okay:
>
> ```
> SET @a = @a + 1;
> ```
>
> For other statements, such as `SELECT`, you might get the results you
>   expect, but this is not guaranteed. In the following statement, you
>   might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an
>   assignment second:
>
> ```
> SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;
> ```
>
> However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user
>   variables is undefined.

The above code does, technically, read the variable in the same *statement*, but it is also in the same *expression*.  The semantics of `if()` (and `case` which I sometimes also use) guarantee the order of evaluation of the expressions.

Comment: I tried your code in the sqlfiddle, but it returns just one row (did your avatar change?)

Comment: @Gordon same here. This seems to only return one row -- Amazon-US

Comment: Its because he didn't assign @P: = platform_type_id in the inner query add that and you should get 1 per platform

Comment: @David542 FYI that fiddle is from my answer to your other question

Comment: @Lamak . . . I had assumed that `platform_type_id` is a number, so I set the variable remembering it to a number.  That caused the problem.

Comment: @Matt . . . Your version is dangerous because you set and use variables in different expressions.  MySQL explicitly does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`.

Comment: @Matt ah, sorry about that (I just accepted your answer). If I would had known you changed your answer I would have not needed to answer this question. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @GordonLinoff good tip, I am intrigued though to learn an example of when/how it will end up messing up? it is something I will look at more, I learned that version from this site and it has always worked as intended in the examples I have worked on, but I see your trick to use the nested if to assign the second variable to constrain the order of evaluation and it looks good so I will take that tip into consideration thanks.

Comment: @Matt . . . I have seem problems arise with some interfaces to MySQL.  Perhaps it is sufficient that the documentation has a clear warning, which I've included in the answer.  This is why when I have answers involving variables in MySQL, the expressions are often rather complicated.  I think I've come across a formulaic way of writing them so they are not too difficult to follow.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just did a search and I found the warning and the documentation but I also found a couple of lengthy articles on forcing order of evaluation and testing the documentations what they call "short comings" most actually show the pattern to typically work, but I guess the issue would be if @p would be assigned prior to being evaluated in the If() perhaps due to indexes or optimization or something.....  I like your method and appreciate the insight!

Answer (score 2):

Try that :

```
SELECT * FROM main_itemmaster
WHERE territory_id LIKE 'US'
GROUP BY platform_type_id

UNION

SELECT * FROM main_itemmaster
WHERE platform_type_id NOT IN (
  SELECT platform_type_id FROM main_itemmaster
  WHERE territory_id LIKE 'US')
GROUP BY platform_type_id
```

Comment: This parses the same table twice  .... you dont need to do that for ordering . Look at my suggestion below @lamak

Comment: @am1704 your suggestion doesn't return the results that op wants, so I'll take this answer over yours

Comment: @elbj interesting approach and yes this is the only answer thus far that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT territory_id, platform_type_id, store_url 
FROM main_itemmaster
GROUP BY platform_type_id
ORDER by if(territory_id ='US',1,99) asc
```

Here is the sqlfiddle for the above