# GROUP_BY, MAX() and only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table:

```
ID  ACCOUNT  BALANCE  TIME
1   Bill     10       1478885000
2   Bill     10       1478885001
3   James    5        1478885002
4   Ann      20       1478885003
5   Ann      15       1478885004
```

I want to get latest (based on TIME) balance of several accounts. I.e.:

```
ACCOUNT  BALANCE
Bill     10
Ann      15
```

I try to use this SQL:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT, BALANCE, max(TIME)
FROM T1
WHERE ACCOUNT IN ( 'Bill', 'Ann')
GROUP BY ACCOUNT
```

I receive error:

`1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'BALANCE' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

I understand the error and tried different SQLs but still do not understand how to retrieve needed data without multiple queries.

P.S. I use MySQl 5.7

Comment: A simple way to solve non aggregated columns: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40578865/439171

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.ACCOUNT, T1.BALANCE, T1.TIME
FROM T1
JOIN (SELECT ACCOUNT, max(TIME) as m_time
      FROM T1
      WHERE T1.ACCOUNT IN ( 'Bill', 'Ann')
      GROUP BY ACCOUNT ) T2
  ON T1.ACCOUNT = T2.ACCOUNT 
 AND T1.TIME = T2.m_time
WHERE T1.ACCOUNT IN ( 'Bill', 'Ann')
```

**EDIT:** for multiple time change better use variables

**[SQL DEMO:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4dc00/1)** I change the date of `Ann` to be the same

```
SELECT ACCOUNT, BALANCE, TIME
FROM (
      SELECT ACCOUNT, BALANCE, TIME, 
             @rn := if(ACCOUNT = @acc, 
                       @rn + 1, 
                       if(@acc := ACCOUNT, 1, 1) as rn                 
      FROM T1, (SELECT @rn := 0, @acc:= '') P
      WHERE ACCOUNT IN ( 'Bill', 'Ann')
      ORDER BY ACCOUNT, TIME desc, BALANCE desc
     ) T
WHERE T.rn = 1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| ACCOUNT | BALANCE |       TIME |
|---------|---------|------------|
|    Bill |      10 | 1478885001 |
|     Ann |      20 | 1478885003 |
```

Comment: @Matt What about placing on both? That way the `JOIN`  is faster because the derived table doesnt have index

Comment: I had the same SQL, but the TIME is not unique in my table. Due to app`s logic I can have several rows with the same TIME for account. As I understand in this case I need one more wrapper SELECT with 'group_by(ACCOUNT)' and 'max(BALANCE)'. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: @VictorMezrin if TIME can be duplicate too then I would use variables to create a row number.  Or perhaps instead of time will ID be unique and always represent a later time?

Comment: If have multiple `TIME` what `BALANCE ` will you like? biggest, random, last id??

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Biggest one. I understand how to modify your SQL to receive that value. Funny that we have no simple way for this task ))

Comment: Yes, in sql server or postgresql you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` here you have to use variables or weird query.

Comment: I  didnt see an easy way to update my query to solve the tie. So check the version with variables

Comment: oops just saw you updated with variables right after posting one myself :) do note that there is one differnece which is how we set the variable to compare previous account.  I used to use your same method until  Gordon Linoff  showed me the doucmenation that says reading and assinging variable in same statement can be problematic.  So the use of a nested if() to assign the previous account forces the order of evaluation..  here is a link on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499031/pre-ordering-a-group-by-statement/39499240#comment66316719_39499240

Comment: Thanks @Matt, Several times I ask in what case that kind of assignment will fail and never got a straight answer. I dont see any example there neither? but at least show a better argument than the usual `I read it on the manual`.

Comment: Thanks again @Matt, I also knew this version before, but the problem was didnt stuck in my brain. But I think now will, you need a special event like this comment to crave the stones :)

Answer (score 0):

You have column in your select that are not in group by

or  you add all the column not in aggregated  function

```
SELECT ACCOUNT, BALANCE, max(TIME)
FROM T1
WHERE ACCOUNT IN ( 'Bill', 'Ann')
GROUP BY ACCOUNT, BALANCE
```

or you   change the sql_mode using

```
 SET sql_mode = ''
```

or

```
  SELECT ACCOUNT, BALANCE, TIME
  FROM T1
  where id  In (
            select id from T1 where (account, time ) in (
                        select account, max(time) 
                        from t1  
                        WHERE ACCOUNT IN ( 'Bill', 'Ann') group by account))
```

Comment: I will receive multiple results for account

Comment: @VictorMezrin   . in mysql  5.7  the use of asimmetric group by (the column in select and not in group by)  is change  you can turn mysql to the previous behaviour setting  the sql_mode  to '';  like in my answer .. in your console  or in you ide just perform  SET sql_mode = '';

Comment: I have also add an query for select the rows you need

Comment: `id (` should be `id = (` ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza   should be in  .. thanks answer  updated .

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear.  If you want the latest balance for each account, here is one way:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where t1.time = (select max(tt1.time) from t1 tt1 where t1.account = tt1.account);
```

You can add the `where` in the outer query to filter for particular accounts.